# Javascript/Node.js array memory management

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, memory

I have a scene of use array as a queue, and I have a question of this scene about the memory.

First, I create a array object in global, and create a producer to push the element to array uninterruptly.

```
var arr = [];

function runningProducer() {
  setInterval(itemProducer, 50);

  function itemProducer() {
    var item = generateItem();
    arr.push(item);
  }
  function generateItem() {
    return { a: Math.random(), };
  }
}
```

Then, I create a customer to clear the array in 1 second

```
function runningCustomer() {
  setInterval(clearQueue, 1000);

  function clearQueue() {
    var t = arr.concat(arr);
    arr = [];
  }
}
```

And running the above functions for a period of time, I found the memory always growing.

```
setInterval(() => {
  var mem = process.memoryUsage();
  console.log(mem);
}, 2000);
```

I think the array should release the memory after set empty, but not.
Please give me some suggetions about this question, and is there any way to release the memory manually in javascript?

Comment: The memory will be cleared when the garbage collector runs, not immediately when you empty the array.

Comment: What is `var t = arr.concat(arr);` supposed to do? If the `t` variable is not referenced elsewhere that whole line is redundant, but if it *is* referenced elsewhere (somehow, in code not shown) then a reference to that array (which is double the size that `arr` was) still exists so it will continue using memory.

Comment: The producer is using the array, you cannot expect the array to be cleared from memory.

Comment: the variable `t` in order to handle the elements in array, for example, storage in database. and even if this variable using memeory, I think it is a constant, but now it is growing uninterruptly. so I'm confused.. @nnnnnn

Comment: I found it is growth uninterruptly, until out of memory.@Barmar

Comment: I think it would be a new array while I empty it. and the old part should be released.isn't it? @AkshayKhandelwal

Comment: Nope. You're using a global array. It'll not empty the memory unless you stop the nodejs process. Remember **global variables are evil**

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal No, that's wrong. The variable is global, but the reference to the his array is released every second and replaced with a new one. The unused arrays will be cleaned up when GC runs.

Comment: JavaScript has function scoping and this variable is in the global scope meaning it remains in memory unless it's deleted or the process stopped. Now how much memory is utilised is dependent on what days it holds. So in fact what I said Is valid. Please lookup to understand the variable scopes in JavaScript

Comment: And to the point where the memory release is concerned, I totally agree where you say that the memory is not immediately released. But in this case the memory will not be released at all

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal I am personally witnessing the memory being released, so what you're saying is not true. You seem to be confusing the concept of variables with the values they refer to. These are two different things.

Comment: Yes. The memory is released, but not the one allocated to array, it's that memory which the objects were allocated which were stored in array (by reference). what you are looking at is the overall memory being used by the app and not the memory being used by array

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal OP's code is creating a new empty array and assigning it to `arr` every second. There isn't just one array. The unused arrays and their contents are being cleaned up by GC.

Comment: No it's reusing the same array. Only cleanup happening is the objects inside the array as they lose reference and are no more being used. The memory that is allocated to the variable arr is still the same and us in use. The objects that are inside array are being cleaned up. I feel that would explain the cleanup that you are witness to

Comment: No, it's replacing the array. Look: `arr = [];`

Comment: Also the OP is not creating a new array. I don't see any new Array() or var arr=[] in the code that is being executed every second.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal Look at his second code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I missed that part. I now agree to what you said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is in Barmar's comment. Reserved memory is not immediately released the moment it is no longer needed. JavaScript relies on garbage collection to detect unused references and release them back to the heap, but garbage collection is an expensive procedure so it is only run every once in a while.

When I try to run your code, the memory usage does increase for a minute or two, and then suddenly goes back to its original value when the garbage collection runs. Perhaps you simply didn't watch the log long enough?

You can manually run garbage collection and see this for yourself by running node with the `--expose-gc` flag and executing `global.gc()` but you should **not** do this in production code unless you have a **very** good reason.

Comment: There is a little problem, I found the usage memory would go back to original memory value, but it will be a little more than the original, about 10kb. every time it's like this.